# What might cause programs to randomly disappear?

Tags: unity

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop, and am having all sorts of strange intermittent problems. I've had unity vanish when restarting, and had to reinstall it twice. I've had Ubuntu Software Center disappear twice and require a reinstall. Terminal has disappeared 3 times. Synapse disappeared after a reboot right after I installed it.

Does anyone know where I might begin in debugging this issue?

Edit: Ran the command suggested

```
?Start-Date: 2013-12-11  13:48:52
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-file' sender=':1.88'
Install: psmisc:i386 (22.20-1ubuntu2, automatic)
Remove: gconf2:amd64 (3.2.6-0ubuntu1), gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.6.1-0ubuntu6), compiz-gnome:amd64 (0.9.10+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1), unity:amd64 (7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1), gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (3.6.1-0ubuntu6), compiz:amd64 (0.9.10+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1), psmisc:amd64 (22.20-1ubuntu2), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.18.2-0ubuntu1), software-center:amd64 (13.10-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2013-12-11  13:48:57
```

Comment: As far as I know, only a root user can remove software like USC and Terminal. Are you sure someone else isn't removing those? Run `less /var/log/apt/history.log` in Terminal and see if they are being removed.

Comment: Hmm. Ran that command and it looks like Remove was run on gnome terminal (which just disapeared again after I posted this question).

Comment: Lol. It just removed Virtualbox. There is a ghost in the machine.

Comment: I would run `passwd` and change the password. If Terminal isn't wokring use TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1)[Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to desktop]. Use `sudo su` to get to the root user and change the password for it also.

Comment: You can also check who has logged in and when by running the `last` command *(look for tty - that may be the first port of call for anyone logging in remotely)* - unless any hackers *(or 'crackers')* modified the log file - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-display-date-and-time-of-login/ .

Change all of your passwords, and if the hacker logged in via `ssh`, run `mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh-OLD`, as they can use RSA keys even if you change your password... Try using some security software, like [ClamAV](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV), or {SELinux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux).

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone else logged in, but I changed my password anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is what was wrong:

"virtualbox is installing 32bit psmisc, which aptdaemon tries to correct in the background, removes it, and by dependency removes a lot of other things"

I think I accidentally downloaded 32bit virtualbox.